# Spring MVC Controller invoked but getting 404 rendering view

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat

My apologies up front if this is answered elsewhere, but some extensive googling of the site has come up with nothing that has helped me thus far, so I'm going to ask here.

So, I have a Spring MVC application that I'm trying to map out using annotations, and while for some requests it works fine, for others I'm getting 404's even after the controller has been invoked.

So, here's my setup...

web.xml :

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.sitemesh.config.ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>requiredVariableFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>requiredVariableFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>requiredVariableFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My appServlet-servlet.xml :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

My controller. It's pretty simple for now :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(UserController.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getBaseUserInfo(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        log.info("got into the user controller");
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("user/baseinfo");

        User user = this.userService.getCurrentUser();

        mav.addObject("user", user);
        log.info("passing off to view");
        return mav;
    }
}
```

I can assure you that I have the relevant jsp at /WEB-INF/pages/user/baseinfo.jsp, so it's not that the JSP isn't there.

Also, my logging shows that the log messages in the controller are being fired, so it gets as far as returning the view, then Tomcat gives me it's oh-so-pretty 404 page, and my logs only say that /user is returning a 404.

Alternatively, though, I have another controller that works perfectly fine here :

```
@Controller
public class BaseController {

    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(BaseController.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private MailChimpService mailChimpService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getHomePage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("index");

        User user = this.userService.getCurrentUser();
        mav.addObject("welcomeMessage", "Hey There!");

        if(user != null) {
            mav.addObject("user", user);
        }

        mav.addObject("newsBlasts", this.mailChimpService.getEmailBlasts());
        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login")
    public ModelAndView getLoginPage (HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response,
            @RequestParam(value="error", required=false, defaultValue=StringUtils.EMPTY) String error) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("login");

        SavedRequest savedRequest = new HttpSessionRequestCache().getRequest(request, response);

        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(error)) {
            mav.addObject("badLogin", true);
        }
        mav.addObject("returnUrl", savedRequest.getRedirectUrl());
        return mav;
    }
}
```

Both of the methods in this controller return perfectly fine and are sitemeshed up and all that with no problems.  I have tried a lot of different suggestions I've seen on this site, and so far nothing seems to be doing the trick.

The only difference between how I'm treating these controllers is that the first one will eventually have nested @RequestMapping's, so it will handle anything under the /user pattern (/user/edit, /user/throwparty, etc.) whereas the second controller is just handling one-off URL's that aren't specifically tied to a particular set of functionality (in this case, the home page and a login page).

Anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: Couldn't it be a problem with sitemesh to handle views in subdirectories ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I thought of that, but when I move the file back to the same directory as the other views, it still doesn't work there, either, so I don't think that's the case.  I also (just to test this) moved my index.jsp into the /pages/user folder as well, altered the view name, and it worked as expected (which is to say, it worked).

Comment: Well then it looks like the problem is in the view itself ... How is it different from the others (which work) ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta Actually, I came to the same conclusion. Ended up I had a few errors, and instead of showing me the errors, Tomcat was just showing a 404 instead.  Added an error page to my view and was able to debug this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error was in the view itself.  Had to add an error page to view the exceptions, but once I did, was able to figure this out.